# An equivalent to Spring Framework's Resource abstraction

Tags: java, spring, resources

Spring Framework provides a wonderful abstraction layer for low-level resource access in Java (the Resource and ResourceLoader interfaces). I'm developing a library which should not be dependent on Spring, and am looking for an equivalent for this capability in a stand-alone Java library. Anyone familiar with one?

Comment: You want to replace a dependency on Spring with a dependency on something else?  What's the point in that?

Comment: Spring is a big framework; the Resource abstraction library is a part of the spring-core JAR, which will pollute the code base with unneeded classes. I much prefer depending on a small, dedicated library. Ideally I would get this support from Apache Commons, Google Guava or similar.

Comment: Depending on *any* library will pollute your code base with unneeded classes, Spring is no different.

Comment: Again - I'm developing a library, I don't want to force my users to use Spring, even if it's just one JAR.

Comment: Again - you're asking for a *different* library to replace this capability in Spring, and you'll be forcing your users to use *that* instead.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the one from Spring by itself?  It doesn't look like it has any dependencies on the rest of Spring.

**Edit**

Not sure I understand the problem - you want something that does exactly the same thing, but doesn't come from Spring?  Is it a licensing issue?

You only need half a dozen classes from it, if you don't want to add them as an extra jar, move them to your own namespace (good idea anyway, in case you do use Spring at some point, after all) and distribute with your library.  Again, assuming your licensing allows it.

If licensing isn't the problem, can you be more specific about why you can't use the Spring implementation in your own library?

Comment: Simply because we don't want any dependency on Spring

Answer (score -2):

You can use Jsr-303 (DI) to match your requirments. The most known implementation is Google Guice. It's a javaEE standard (maybe JavaSE).

Comment: I'm not looking for dependency injection; I'm looking for low-level resource access (classpath vs url vs filesystem) abstracion...